# Do I have to seal gaps in my plywood subfloor before I install base cabinets?

Tags: subfloor, cabinets

I have diagonal board above my floor joists. My contractor added a 1/2" ply subfloor on top of that.

The diagonals have maybe a 1/4" gap between them.

You can see the diagonals in the picture below. There's a gap between the subfloor and the wall. And you can see a small opening (the dark/black space in the middle of the picture) that basically goes to the crawl space.

[image: subfloor/wall gap]
[image: wider view]

Should I seal this gap between my wall and subfloor? I'm concerned that bc of the spacing between the diagonals beneath the subfloor my cabinets may be exposed to the crawl space. Basically exposed to the elements and maybe critters.

If I should seal that gap what should I use?

Do I need to just vacuum up all the dust and debris and use a silicone caulk?

Comment: Why is there no vapor barrier or insulation there? Typically your drywall isn't part of that system.

Comment: Vapor barrier for the floor? The gap you see is on the floor...

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a wall, floor, or ceiling. If it's an exterior plane it should be sealed and insulated properly. A bead of caulk doesn't do that (especially if it's against drywall).

Comment: We pulled up the old subfloor and there wasn't any vapor barrier there. The house was built in 1939. Is there anything I can do now? I can't install a vapor barrier now.

Comment: You said it was a crawl space. Can't get in there do fix up the insulation?

Comment: Crawlspce is under the floor

Comment: LOL. They always are. If you have no other options, use expanding spray foam (careful--it's sticky!) and silicone caulk to do the best you can.

Comment: LOL. I don't understand your c moment about using crawl space to fix

Comment: Vapor barriers trap moisture; usually not a good thing.  I would advise against a vapor barrier on the floor or wall or ceiling.  The little hole is not a problem in that sealing the crawl space from the living space is not the purpose of the subfloor.  The sub floor provides structural support for the floor finish.  Insulation and vapor retarders serve the aforementioned purpose.  If you are worried about bugs, you have alot more "holes" to worry about; I would not get hung up on these few.

Comment: How about just expanding foam?

Comment: @Damon, I'm not sure where you are in the world, but where I am vapor barriers are a critical component of a building envelope. Your blanket statement is puzzling.